# Android: Convertion from string to date

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I'm new to android. I have a table in database which has date column as String type and stores the date in this format "dmyyyy" I need to retrieve date present in this format from sqlite database and update that value to DatePicker view. How do i achieve this, please help me.

e.g: "1102012" (1-Nov-2012)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would "1102012" mean the 1st of *November*? Wouldn't it mean October? Or if you're using 0-based months, what's to stop that string meaning the 11th of January?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Great observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, why are you storing them as strings in that format in the first place? You've got a thoroughly ambiguous format - assuming you just made a mistake in your example, how would you tell the difference between "January 11th" and "November 1st"? Both would be "111" followed by the year.

As I understand it, SQLite usually uses ISO-8601 representations of dates and times - that's what its [date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) use, and that's what I'd expect client libraries to expose.

Anyway, when it comes to parsing, you could *either* use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a third-party date/time API and *much* better than the built-in `Date` and `Calendar` classes, or you could use `SimpleDateFormat`. I suggest you explicitly specify the `Locale` (ideally something like `Locale.US`, *not* the user's locale - this is just for storage) the time zone (again, you should almost certainly use UTC rather than the user's time zone) and the pattern (e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd` for ISO-8601). Then use `parse` to retrieve a `Date`... which you'll probably want to then set into a `Calendar` with the same time zone, in order to get at more useful information.

Comment: Hello Jon, thanks for your answer, I will really change the way of storing date in my database, but the thing is I'm reading the date value from DatePicker view and storing it in database, that DatePicker is giving me the value in this format. 
I will do change the format of date before storing in database Please forgive me for my poor understandings and my language as well, as I'm just 1 year old baby boy for this programming, anyways sir, I really thank your support.

Comment: @Bharadwaj: The `DatePicker` gives you the individual values via `getMonth`, `getDayOfMonth` etc. You can then put that into whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
String dateStr = "5/31/2011";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The date should be in the format DDMMYYYY. The format DMYYYY is unparsable. Add following methods to your class;

```
private int getDay(String s) {
    return Integer.valueOf(s.substring(0, 2));
}

private int getMonth(String s) {
    return Integer.valueOf(s.substring(2, 4));
}

private int getYear(String s) {
    return Integer.valueOf(s.substring(4));
}
```

Then setup DatePicker like this :

```
String dateString = "01112012";
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
datePicker.updateDate(getYear(dateString), getMonth(dateString), getDay(dateString));
```

Comment: Why would you write your own parsing code rather than using the built-in API? (I'd also suggest that a format of yyyy-MM-dd would be better, as it's sortable.)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's what he asked for. And I think he actually meant MMDDYYYY format but messed up the example. The example date given is unusable. Also I don't know of a builtin API that could parse MMDDYYYY.

Comment: Well, he asked how to parse a value. Reinventing the wheel doesn't sound like a good idea to me. (Also, why aren't you even using substring?) Actual MMddyyyy format (or ddMMyyyy which seems more likely to me) is fine to parse, as that's *always* got two-digit month and day values. `SimpleDateFormat` will work perfectly with that.

Comment: Further notes: No validation; curious use of `StringBuilder` when the more natural input would be `String`; needlessly inefficient string concatenation.

Comment: Oh, and the string concatenation doesn't even work correctly. It will add together the Unicode values of the characters, so an input of "12345678" would end up with the day value being parsed as 99, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet You have to understand that I've have never studied java formally. I just found out that `String` have a `charAt(..)` method. LOL. Why do you say that the string concatenation is inefficient?

Comment: I have fixed the concatenation.

Comment: Hooray, now you're creating a new string for each character in the string. I repeat: why aren't you using `substring`? And why would you want to reinvent the wheel? This simply isn't a good approach.

Comment: Modified to use `substring`. Again the reason I wasn't using `substring` is just because I wasn't aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: Right, leaving only the fact that we're now not validating the data, and it's *still* cleaner to just parse once, to the more "native" representation (`Date` / `Calendar`).

Comment: Well, so long.. If you want any more change, feel free to edit. I'm gonna sleep.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for my igorance, I didn't realize that you are a legend. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts